# How can I add a product in amazon using the amazon API?

Tags: amazon-mws

I'm doing a project using ebay and amazon api.

I've uploaded products to ebay sandbox using the api.

But I searched for api to add products in amazon api.

Is there any documentation or reference to do it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to use the Amazon MWS API (it's not the same as AWS product API) in order to upload your products to Amazon. 
[Here](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_IfNew.html) you can read everything you need to know about MWS.

For your particular problem, you'll have to submit a feed which contains the product data you want to upload. Here is the documentation about Amazon's [feed mechanism](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_Overview.html)  and [feed submit operation](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html).

**UPDATE:**

There are the feed client libraries, with [the code samples](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/179-8538417-1386210?ie=UTF8&group=bde&section=feeds&version=latest), for C#, Java and PHP. 
For example, if you download the Java client library, you'll find a great example within the file on the path: **src\com\amazonaws\mws\samples\SubmitFeedSample.java**, etc.

If you are using another language, you'll have to write your own code, but the approach should be straightforward: you have a WS end-point (i.e. https://mws.amazonservices.com)  and you have to execute the *SubmitFeed* operation against it.

**An XML sample of the feed content**

[Feed content example.](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/apa_guide/Step_2_Submit_your_Feed_Content.html)

Comment: Thanks, but is there any sample code to start?. because, I studied all. but still don't know how to implement it.

Comment: @CyberMJ is there any sample of how to write the feedContent?

Comment: @yuyue007 did you find any yet?

Comment: @yuyue007 Sorry, I missed your question. If I got it, you need an XML sample of the feed content? I updated the answer.

Comment: @wutzebaer The answer has been updated with the feed content sample.

Comment: @yuyue007 in meantime i found some other samples in the internet, but i cannot find a definition from Amazon, how do they know the XML format?

Comment: @wutzebaer The link behind the "feed content example" text (the bottom of the answer) doesn't help you? There is an XML format provided by the Amazon, please have a look.

Comment: no not really, but i found this : https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl.pdf

Comment: @wutzebaer  I have find some XSD available, https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/Product.xsd , we can get all other related XSD from it's hierarchy.

Comment: Can We Use this Api to create a website which shows our products and create orders which will then be handled by amazon