# Putting advertisement item on amazon, ebay

Tags: amazon-web-services, ebay-api, amazon-mws

I have my own online selling stole.

I want to put some item on amazon, ebay. 
I dont know how to proceed, any help would be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Amazon Marketplace which has its own API. The Amazon Product Advertising API is only for querying for product data.

**Small update**: Look at this question for more information:
[How to add product in amazon using amazon api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728718/how-to-add-product-in-amazon-using-amazon-api)